# Create a grayscale image from a color coded source image in Python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to convert a color-coded image to grayscale. The colors in that image correspond to given values (e.g. black is 0 and red is 25) like on this color scale.

[image]

Is there a way to convert this image to grayscale and keep that color gradient, so that 0 on the scale remains black and 25 is shown as white?

I tried to convert it with matplotlib and also cv2 but ended up with grayscale images, that did not respect my given color gradient. I would appreciate an answer very much. Thank you!

Comment: Since your gradient is known, you'd need to write a function that maps colors in the input image to positions on that gradient.

Comment: Is this solely for the above gradient, or are there others of a different size and/or colours and with different start/end points, i.e. not 0..25 ?

Comment: I want to convert color-coded brain scans. In the images, low (blue) values show brain tissue that is well supplied with blood and high (red) values indicate areas of stroke. But the gradient and the range of values (0 up to 25) is consistent in all the images.

Comment: You say *"black is zero"* but then *"blue is low"*?

Comment: Are you expecting a floating point value between 0..25, or an integer?

Comment: Sorry, that was misleading. The values 0 up to 25 indicate a time in seconds for a contrast media to get its maximal enrichment in a brain region. 0 or black means there is no contrast media (or no vital brain), short times (purple, blue, and green) show normal brain tissue, and high red-coded areas have a prolonged perfusion time. My plan was to convert this color scale to values between 0 and 255 corresponding a 8-bit grayscale image.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your image and make sure everything is correct and well-explained in there rather than forcing folks to read through all the comments. Please also show an input and an output image, without borders or decorations and the the first few values as text from the input image and corresponding values from the output image. I doubt many of the programmers on here, including myself, have any idea about *"maximal enrichment'* or *"perfusion"* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the tools you use you can

- read/convert the color-coded image as RGB,
- convert RGB to grayscale

or

- convert the colors in the gradient to grayscale,
- read/convert the color-coded image using that grayscale palette.

The second approach is more efficient.

---

**Update:**

Upon reading your last comment (which should be in the original question), the options become

- read/convert the color-coded image as RGB,
- convert RGB to grayscale,
- rescale by multiplying the pixel values by 10

or

- convert the colors in the gradient to grayscale, rescaled to 0-255,
- read/convert the color-coded image using that grayscale palette.